# javascript file input onchange not working [ios safari only]

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, onchange

The code below works everywhere except on safari mobile.
Apparently the onchange is never triggered.

```
 // create a hidden file input element
 var input  = document.createElement("input");
 input.type = "file";
 
 // when the input content changes, do something
 input.onchange =
 function(event)
 {
  // upload files
 }

 // Trigger file browser
 input.click();
```

I have found similar examples however they all refer to scenarios where there is even a form of some other visible representation of the file input and they all involve form-clearing workarounds. That wouldn't work here.

This code is being called upon clicking a picture, in order to upload a new one as a replacement.

Any hints? Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `onchange` is not triggered until the Client actually selects a file or files. `.click()` may not work in some Browsers on `<input type='file' />`.

Comment: .click works everywhere for what I have been able to test, and the file selector is opened correctly on safari iOS. What isn't triggered is onchange *after* the file has been selected and the select dialog closed.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'll be damned: on iOS safari two extra conditions are necessary compared to other browsers:

1) The input must be actually appended to the DOM.

2) setting .onchange won't work: addEventListener must be used instead.

Comment: Thanks man! Spend half day fighting this. Strangely it's not pure iOS issue. For example iOS 11 on iPad worked, but iOS on iPhone (6+ with iOS 11 and 7 with iOS 10) didnt.

Comment: Doesn't work. Can you clarify why or where you found this information please? All I get from a change event is an object that says { isTrusted: true}. On other browsers I get the event.target.files array.

Comment: Make sure you don't remove the input until after your onchange fires! I was dumbly removing it right after the click event.

Comment: Using addEventListener wasn't necessary in my case, but adding the input to the dom did the trick: 
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.onchange = () => {
      // Handle change event
      document.body.removeChild(input)
    }

Comment: can confirm, adding it to the body was enough to make it work.

Comment: @resle thank you a ton for this. how did you figure this out?

Comment: @UladKasach  soul-crushing trial and error :)

Comment: I solve this by input.onchange, code like below: const input = document.getElementById('video-input'); input.onchange = (e) => {
                console.log('onchange');
            }, and input component style set visibility: hidden

Comment: Found out that using addEventListener is indeed required. Adding it to the body alone is not sufficient. For whatever reason iOS Safari does not fire `.onchange` for photos taken directly with the camera (i.e., using the `take photo` option). It does, strangely, fire `.onchange` for photos taken from the `photo library`, which made me not realize the `take photo` option was failing for a while.

Comment: Still I am struggling the issue using change or onchane in IOS safari. Any suggestion how to solve change or onchange issues on ios safari?

Comment: Does anyone happen to know if it's still a issue in newest version? which version started it to work again?

Comment: For me the problem are only .heic and .heif filees => change event is not triggered

Comment: Still need to append to DOM, in iOS 17.0

Comment: iOS 17.3 nothing works (addEventListener & append to dom) , safari is the new IE and I hope apple disappears for it

Answer (score 3):

should append input element to the real dom.

```js
    // create a hidden file input element
 var input  = document.createElement("input");
 input.type = "file";

 document.body.appendChild(input);

 // when the input content changes, do something
 input.onchange =
 function(event)
 {
  // upload files
document.body.removeChild(input)
 }

 // Trigger file browser
 input.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem in iOS 12 / Safari 12 and just creating an `addEventListener` solved the issue for me.
e.g.

```
fileInputFiled.addEventListener("change", (event) => { this.submit(event) })
```