# Why onchange function not working in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

Please tell me, if you change the field value in the middle, then the onchange function does not work. If you write numbers at the end, then the function works. The problem is only in the safari browser. What could be the problem?

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  phone: function() {
    var maskList = [{
        "code": "+7 ### ### ## ##",
        "country": "RU"
      },
      {
        "code": "+380 ## ### ## ##",
        "country": "UA"
      }
    ];
    var change = function(e) {
      if (e.type == 'paste') $(this).val('');

      cursor_start = $(this).prop('selectionStart');
      cursor_end = $(this).prop('selectionEnd');
      let matrix = '###############';
      if ($(this).val()[0] == '+') {
        matrix = '+##############';
      }
      maskList.forEach(item => {
        let code = item.code.replace(/[\s#]/g, ''),
          phone = $(this).val().replace(/[\s#-)(]/g, '');
        if (phone.includes(code)) {
          matrix = item.code;
        }
      });

      let i = 0,
        val = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

      value = matrix.replace(/(?!\+)./g, function(a) {
        return /[#\d]/.test(a) && i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) : i >= val.length ? '' : a;
      });
      if (val.replace(/\D/g, '').length > value.replace(/\D/g, '').length) {
        value += val.replace(/\D/g, '').slice(value.replace(/\D/g, '').length);
      }
      $(this).val(value);

      return this;
    }

    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).on('load keyup paste', change);
      $(this).trigger('load');
    });
  }
});
$(".phone").phone();
$(".phone").on("change", function() {
  console.log("change");
})
$(".no_phone").on("change", function() {
  console.log("change");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="phone" value="+380000000000">
<input type="text" class="no_phone" value="123">
```

P.s Only open in safari.

This does not work only for the field on which this function is hung. Other field normally fulfills onchange.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript file input onchange not working \[ios safari only\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664777/javascript-file-input-onchange-not-working-ios-safari-only)

Comment: @CharloPoitras This does not work only for the field on which this function is hung. Other field normally fulfills onchange.

Comment: JavaScript setting the value does not trigger events.

Comment: I'm using permissions API and the same thing happens with microphone query onchange. Mac Safari ignores it while in Chrome it works nice and smooth.

Answer (score 4):

IOS tends to not fire change events when you change the value of their inputs.

If you change `onchange` to `onblur` it works for iOS but not others. The fix I eventually came to was to use BOTH `onblur` and `onchange`. Seems redundant but has the desired effect.

```
$(".phone").on("change blur", function() {
  console.log("change");
})
```

Comment: It's not just iOS, it doesn't fire for me on MacOS also.

Comment: This does not work only for the field on which this function is hung. Other field normally fulfills onchange.

Comment: was the same problem and answer for MacOS

Comment: Then in google chrome the function will be executed 2 times...

Comment: Just, check if browser is safari or not.  var safariBrowser = window.safari !== undefined;
if (safariBrowser) { // The blur events here }; (this code only detect safari on MacOS, nothing about IOS)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, the solve is just as easy as going to whatever file is included in your project, *right click* on the icon, click on *get info* go all the way down and make sure that in *sharing and permission* everyone is allowed to both write and read. the refresh the page and your feature will wok

Comment: Hi, this is unclear; can you add some details to clarify how this can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can just set a condition when page load in iphone and when page laod in other os.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))
{
      $(".no_phone").on("blur", function() {
         alert("changed");
      })
}
else{
      $(".no_phone").on("change", function() {
         alert("changed");
      })
});
```